# typescript and @types/react errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm still learning to use typescript with react. Due to how slow [react-scripts-ts](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript#react-scripts-ts--) was, I was turned off from it. I've tried the new typescript setup with babel 7 ([react-webpack-typescript-babel](https://github.com/a-tarasyuk/react-webpack-typescript-babel)) and its exceedingly fast. However there are some basic errors that I can't resolve.

Even though the project runs, in vscode I get the following errors:

- [ts] Module ...@types/react... has no exported member 'Component'
- [ts] Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'Counter'
- [ts] Module ...@types/react... has no exported member 'SFC'
- [ts] Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'
- and more...

I'm assuming this is a @types/react and typescript issue.

1. Is @types/react not being updated?
2. How I can get the other properties to show up?
3. I also don't understand when to download from
   @types vs use the @types found in some packages other than reading
   the package description.

Comment: `Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'` it seems you're using an older version of typescript. That's an option from typescript `>=2.7`

Comment: Well `react-webpack-typescript-babel` is using `v3.1.6` so your local typescript might not be the issue. Maybe you have an older version of typescript globally installed?

Comment: @lleon Wow. I thought I removed all globals but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @lleon input, an old typescript version was the cause of my headache. I removed it `npm un -g typescript`, added vscode user setting `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"` and restarted vscode. Works well so far.